# Is this a Firefox 41.0.2 bug with fieldset?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have some forms with fieldsets with abolute position. An algorithm check if fieldset don't overlap and in this case modify the height of that fieldset by modifying elem.style.height. This works just fine for every browsers I have tested so far until FireFox 41.0.2 version.

Here is a simplified fiddle reproducing the case : https://jsfiddle.net/ty44monr/

```
<div id="parent">
    <fieldset id="mydiv" class="default"></fieldset>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>


.default{
    position:absolute;
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
    top:10px;
    border:5px solid #808000;

}


function recurceDiv(elem){
     //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += elem.nodeType;
    if (elem.nodeType == 1){
        elem.style.height = 300 + 'px';
        var children = elem.childNodes;
        for (var i=0,len=children.length;i<len;i++){
            recurceDiv(children[i]);

            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "t : "+elem.offsetHeight + "  ";
        }
    }
}

recurceDiv(document.getElementById("parent"));
```

The fieldset take correctly the 300px height (+ margin / padding) in Chrome, opera, IE11 but not in FireFox 41.0.2 (but works in FireFox 40.0)

If I use a div instead of the fieldset it works well : https://jsfiddle.net/64a5znuh/

Does somebody has an explaination to this FireFox behavior or should I post a ticket in Firefox bugzilla?

Thanks

--
Edit 26/10 :

Firefox bug confirmed bugzilla: [Bug 1217831 - Modify the height of a fieldset by js doesn't work under certain circumstances](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1217831)

Comment: Please feel free to post that information as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox bug confirmed bugzilla: [Bug 1217831 - Modify the height of a fieldset by js doesn't work under certain circumstances](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1217831)